# Command to sum substrings of a file

Tags: unix

I have a text file say example.txt. Its content shown below

```
6.dat~15712
7.dat~14911
8.dat~25028
9.dat~13565
```

My aim to calculate sum of all the numbers that occurs after `~`. How can that be done ?

Answer (score 0):

this should do it :

```
result=0; 
while read line 
do 
  ((result+=$(echo "$line" | cut -d'~' -f2))) 
done < your_file.txt
echo $result
```